# mp4 file won't play in html5 video player

Tags: html, video

I'm trying to create a html5 videoplayer on my site, but if when I try to insert the file like so:

```
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay>
  <source src="gevelreclame.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="gevelreclame.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

it doesn't work at al, I have another video file (also mp4) which just works when implemented in the same way

***EDIT***

both the files are not working now, i've changed only the filenames and they just don't work anymore..

Comment: Any errors on the console? What browser are you using? Could you prepare a small jsfiddle example?

Comment: the example can be found here (i just uploaded the files to my school's server) http://wouter.aoweb.nl/htmlvideo/

Comment: i am using firefox the latest version of it, i also tried testing in chrome, edge, ie, opera and nothing seems to work

Comment: Hmm, I could think of different codecs, red from different browsers. Maybe every browser tries to play the video, gets a valid response when looking for it on the server, but isn't able to play it then. Have you tried to add a `codecs=""` inside your type like: `type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2"'` ? As summarized in this wikipedia-article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support) different browsers support different codecs.

Comment: your page isn't loading for me to see